# Is it possible to make a successful ajax get request to google.com from any page that has jquery loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cross-domain

I want to fetch google.com successfully, I don't care if I use jquery, I just want to fetch it somehow (i.e. not using a javascript library is fine, e.g. XMLHttpRequest is fine too). Here's an example ajax call I've put into my console from a test.html page on my local machine that loads jquery:

```
var url = 'http://google.com';
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  error: function(req, resp) {
    console.log('Error fetching ' + url);

    console.log("req:");
    console.log(req);

    console.log("resp:");
    console.log(resp);    
    },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("success! here's the data:");
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your apostrophe is acting as an end-quote; either escape it with a backslash (`\'`) or use double quotes outside (`"success! here's ..."`)

Comment: Good call, edited. Now I just need to make a rule in JSHint to stop telling me that single quotes are preferred.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just arbitrarily grab other sites due to the Same Origin Policy. You're going to need to build an intermediary on your server that does that data grab (in PHP you could use `file_get_contents` or `curl`) and then THAT script (which is on your domain) would be the target of the ajax call

Comment: Oh, I guess there could be some instances where that wouldn't be true. If you convert this page into a native app (using a UIWebView in iOS for instance) I believe it runs as a server, so would in fact be able to directly query other URLs. Is that at all relevant to your project?

Comment: I need the chrome extension to access www.google.com, that's what I'm writing. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-cross-domain-from-chrome-extensions seems relevant, and I've included google.com in the manifest.json, but it keeps failing.

Comment: This is the relevant portion from the manifest.json: https://gist.github.com/ccc35a876087bc638720